# Reading and writing a 5 byte long

Tags: java

I'm dealing with a buffer that reads an unsigned short and then a 3 byte integer and combines them. The problem is I can't figure out how to correctly add an integer so that the number read (the "result") is the same as the number I added to the buffer.

```
long val1 = (long) buffer.getUnsignedShort();
long val2 = (long) buffer.get3ByteInt();
long result = val2 + (val1 << 32);

public int getUnsignedShort() {
    return (byteArray[position++] & 255 << 8) + byteArray[position++] & 255;
}
public int get3ByteInt() {
    return (byteArray[position++] & 255 << 16) + (byteArray[position++] & 255 << 8) + byteArray[position++] & 255;
}
```

Comment: 3*8=32? (Did you trying asking a duck?)

Comment: Using `position++` multiple times in one expression technically works, but it’s bad practice and is very easy to mess up inadvertently with future changes.  A [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) would make this whole thing considerably easier.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that `3 * 8 = 24` not 32, you also have problems with operator precedence. The shift operator has higher precedence than the bitwise and. So your code re-writes to:

```
return (byteArray[position++] & (255 << 8)) + (byteArray[position++] & 255);
```

Not what you want. Same problem in the other function. You can fix this using parentheses:

```
long val1 = buffer.getUnsignedShort();
long val2 = buffer.get3ByteInt();
long result = val2 | (val1 << 24);

public int getUnsignedShort() {
    return ((byteArray[position++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (byteArray[position++] & 0xFF);
}
public int get3ByteInt() {
    return ((byteArray[position++] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((byteArray[position++] & 0xFF) << 8) | (byteArray[position++] & 0xFF);
}
```

I've also changed the `+` signs to `|` as it is clearer to me that is a bitwise operation. I also changed `255` to `0xFF` for the same reason. That's just my preference. And there is no need to cast `int` to `long`.